# How do I transfer from a self hosted blog to WordPress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

Normally, people move from WordPress.com to a self hosted blog. I want to move from a self hosted blog to WordPress.com. Is this possible?

This may be off topic but since it involves going from self hosted I think it is relevant.

Comment: There is a guide [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-from-self-hosted-wordpress-to-wordpress-com/) that shows how to transfer from self hosted to WordPress.com.

Comment: You should ask WordPress.com support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a guide [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-from-self-hosted-wordpress-to-wordpress-com/) that shows how to transfer from self hosted to WordPress.com.

Go to tools and export.
Go to tools and import.